# Android Application Errors "Error in an XML file: aborting build."

Tags: android

Im new to this, so sry if this is a very obvious thing, but when i try to start this it shows me these Errors:

Error in an XML file: aborting build.
error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element

```
 <LinearLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.meineapp.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
    android:text="Button" />

Button btnActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnActivity);

btnActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent in = new Intent(StartActivityActivity.this,secondActicity.class);
startActivity(in);
        }
});




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for android development. You don't write java code in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You placed java code into XML file. This is not going to work. You need to go thru some elementary tutorial for Android first.